# how to validate a field with the style =display:none?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate, hidden-field

i have a field with display:none property.Its like,when the user clicks on "yes" radio button then the file upload field will appear and validation takes place for file upload also.In this case,I used  **ignore[]**  to make that validation work but what happens is,even if i click no,then validation for file upload is happening.

here is my code

```
  <li >
   <p>
    <label for="rad">radio label:
    </label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="rad" value="yes" style="width:20px">&nbsp; Yes&nbsp;&nbsp;</input>
    <input type="radio" name="rad" value="no" style="width:20px">&nbsp; No</input><br/>
    <label for="rad" class="error" style="display:none">This field is required</label>
   </p>
    <p>
        <input type="file" name="fupl" style="display:none;margin-top:10px" id="fup"/>
        <label for="fupl" class="error" style="display:none;color:red">This field is required</label>
    </p>
</li>
<br>
<li>
    <label>checkbox label
    </label><br><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="cb" value="tick" style="width:20px">&nbsp;&nbsp;<small>checkbox field<small></input>
    <br>
    <label for="fee" class="error" style="display:none">This field is required</label>
</li>
<br>
<li>
<input type="submit" class="button" value="SUBMIT" style="float:right"/>
</li>
<script>
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
        $("input[type='radio']").change(function(){
        if($(this).val()=="yes")
        {
        $("#fup").show();
        }
        else
        {
        $("#fup").hide();
        }
        });
        });
    </script>
```

this is my jquery

```
 $('#form').validate({
    ignore :[],
     rules: {   
        fupl: {
            required: true,
            accept:'docx|doc'
            },
        cb:
            {
            required:true
            }
         }
         });
```

Comment: As I showed [you in my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15148001/594235), your code already appeared to be doing what you asked.  But your title says this:  _"Q: how to validate a field with the style =display:none?"_  If you don't want to validate a hidden field, then remove the `ignore: []` option.  Then I added code to hide the error when the field becomes hidden:  http://jsfiddle.net/y5ghU/4/

Comment: Yeeeep.... Looks like a dupe to me too.

Answer (score 0):

use `fup` instead of `fup1` in your validation script.

Comment: fup is my id.fupl is the name of the field.Thats why have used it in my script

Answer (score 0):

You can add the rules for your file upload in your change function, instead of having them always in there:

```
var fuplRules = {
    required: true,
    accept: 'docx|doc'
};


$("input[type='radio']").change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == "yes") {
        $("#fup").show().rules('add', fuplRules);
    } else {
        $("#fup").hide().rules('remove');
    }
});
```

Or, you can keep your setup the way it is now and just change the `required: true` to be `required: 'input[name="rad"][value="yes"]:checked'`.  This uses the [dependency-expression](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/required#dependency-expression) version of the required rule.

Working Example #1: http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/WFKfq/

Working Example #2: http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/WFKfq/1/